# GRPC Client on .Net Framework 4.7.2 using Grpc.Net.Client and server on .Net6 fails. HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to get a .Net Framework v4.7.2 Client using Grpc.Net.Client to communicate with a server application that runs on .Net6.0 but it fails. The server shows the error message:

*"HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint."*

The client shows:

*Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. WinHttpException: Error 12030 calling WinHttpWriteData, 'The connection with the server was terminated abnormally'.*

I've implemented a custom HttpHandler (Http2CustomHandler) to force Http/2.

**Custom HTTP Handler --**

```
public class Http2CustomHandler : WinHttpHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Version = new Version("2.0");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Client Implementation (Console Application) --**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7193", new GrpcChannelOptions
    {
        HttpHandler = new Http2CustomHandler { }, 
        Credentials = Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl
    }))
    {
        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        var reply = client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }    
}
```

Packages

Grpc.Net.Client.2.56.0

Grpc.Tools.2.57.0

Google.Protobuf.3.24.2

**Server Implementation --**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(7193, o =>
    {
        o.UseHttps();
        o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
    });
});

builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
```

Server uses the package Grpc.AspNetCore.2.56.0

**Proto Implementation --**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcServer";

package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

By using the custom HttpHandler (Http2CustomHandler) to force Http/2 I was expecting to see the message

```
Greeting: Hello GreeterClient
```

on the client side, but the code fails on the line

```
var reply = client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient"})...
```

When I run the same client code on a .Net6 Client it works fine.

Comment: Inheriting from WinHttpHandler isn't needed. Does it work if you use WinHttpHandler without inheritance?

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/pull/2288 has a related fix (it will be in the next grpc-dotnet release)